# マストドンへ画像を送る

Tags: swift3

現在、Mastodonへ画像を投稿するプログラムを組んでいるのですが、下記の投稿のものを参考に組みましたが
http://qiita.com/aryzae/items/8c16bc456588c1251f48#_reference-32d9e31807ff872c27f8
送る際は、85406 bytesのデータ量を確認しているのですが受信が0bytesと表示され悩んでいます。
本来であれば、json形式で幾らかの受信があるはずなのですが・・・
本家のGitHubのAPI一覧を拝見し(クロームで翻訳)、解決できずに困っています。

よろしくお願いします。

```
    func testToot(){
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let i = Item()
        let url = URL(string:"https://pawoo.net/api/v1/media")!
        let param:[String:String] = ["access_token":i.getItem(clum: "access_token") as! String]


        let image:Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named:"a.jpg")!,0.8)! as Data
        let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
        var req = URLRequest(url:url)
        req.httpMethod = "POST"
        req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        req.addValue("multipart/form-data;boundary=\(boundary)",forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

        req.httpBody = createBody(_param: param, _key:"file", imageData: image, _boundary: boundary)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: req,completionHandler:{data,response,error in do{
            print(response!)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }


    func createBody(_param:[String:String],_key:String,imageData:Data,_boundary:String)->(Data){
        let file = "a.jpg"
        let type = "image/jpeg"
        var body = Data();
            for(key,val) in _param {
                body.append("--`\(_boundary)\r\n")
                body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\(key)")
                body.append("\(val)\r\n")
            }
        body.append("--\(_boundary)\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data;name=\"\(_key)\"; filename=\"\(file)\"\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Type \(type)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageData)
        body.append("r\n")
        body.append("--\(_boundary)--\r\n")
        return body
    }
}
extension Data{
    mutating func append(_ str:String){
        let data = Data(str.utf8)
        return self.append(data)
    }
}
```

responseの中身

```
 { URL: https://pawoo.net/api/v1/media } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 12 May 2017 12:44:39 GMT";
    Vary = Origin;
    "x-request-id" = "aasf0bb-fb82-45c1-34d0-676ffc1aww15";
    "x-runtime" = "0.155211";
} }
```

Comment: 引用記事中には受信データに関して何かを表示すると言うコードが存在しませんので、「受信が0bytesと表示され」の部分が意味を成していません。事象が再現できるようなあなたのコードをお示しください。(引用記事のように断片を切れ切れに示されると処理の流れが正しいかどうかがわからないので、「コピペすれば動作確認できる」レベルの、処理全体をつなげたものをご提示ください。)

Comment: コードのご掲載ありがとうございます。いくつか気になる点があるのですが、`let i = Item()` `i.getItem(clum: "access_token")`では確実に正しいaccess_tokenが取得できているのでしょうか？`print(response!)`では **_0 bytes_** との表示にはならないはずですが、結果はどのように確認されたのでしょうか？また、その行を`print(data, response, error)`と書き換えると(警告は無視してください)どのような出力が得られるでしょうか。`print(response!)`の行まで実行が進んでいるのであれば、なんらかのエラー応答が返ってきている可能性が高いと思います。

Comment: 返信ありがとございます。<pre>i.getItem(clum:"access_token")</pre>で確かにトークン取得成功しております。また、responsの中身を確認したところstatus:400とありました。返信ステータスは上記に掲載しておきますので確認をお願いしていただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

気になった点をいくつか挙げてみます。

- testToot 内で Content-Type を 2回指定している。
- createBody 内、boundary に backquote(`) が混入している。
- Content-Disposition の最後に `\r\n\r\n` がない。
- Content-Type の後に `:` がない。
- `\r` であるはずのところ、`r` となっている。